# CASE WHEN SQL Type Statement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column called Class which is a calculated column.
Basically when the Math class is NA then the class will be the CS class, otherwise it will be vice versa.

How can I do this in python? Table name is Classes

```
MathClass |  CSClass |  Class
------------------------------
Trig      |  NA      |  Trig
NA        |  Java    |  Java
NA        |  Python  |  Python
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the missing value with empty string and add these columns up

```
Classes.fillna(value='').sum(axis=1)
```